# How to check value in javascript variable for include number or not?

Tags: javascript

How to check value in javascript variable for include number or not ?

eg: `var test = "abcd1234";`

this var `test` include lower case and number.

How to use javascript to check var value include number or not ?

I tried to use `isNaN` function

```
var test = "abcd1234";
var test = isNaN(test);
if(test === true)
{ alert("not include number");
else
{ alert("include number");
```

But this code alert `not include number` because `isNaN` will check all data of var.  but i want to check only a part of var. How can i do that ?

Comment: Are you looking to simply find out whether a string contains at least one digit or is your criteria more sophisticated?  Have you considered using regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

You must use regex instead.

```js
var test = /\d/.test("abcd1234");
if (test === true) {
  alert("include number");
} else {
  alert("not include number");
}
```